# Restrict specific Pages to Load in WKWebview?

Tags: html, swift, webview

How can i prevent any web page to load in WEKWebView?
In-order to load whole website i am using this code

```
self.webview.customUserAgent = userAgent 
self.webview.navigationDelegate = self
self.webview.load(URLRequest.init(url: URL.init(string: snapshot.value as! String)!))
```

but know i want to restrict some specific page to load in this webview by using NavigationDelegate methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice way to do this is to compare `URL Host` which can be done using the following approach

```
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {

        let exceptedHosts: [String] = [
            "facebook.com", 
            "m.facebook.com"
        ]

        if let host = navigationAction.request.url?.host {
            if exceptedHosts.contains(host) {
                decisionHandler(.cancel)
                return
            }
        }

        decisionHandler(.allow)
    }
```

This will prevent any url with `facebook.com` or `m.facebook.com` from being opened, add any hosts to the array to except them from being opened.

Please don't forget to set delegate in `viewDidLoad`

```
    webview.navigationDelegate = self
```

Comment: https://github.com/dequin-cl/WKContentRuleExample#wkcontentruleexample